# Given a parse tree, how can I extract words to create a sentence?

Tags: java, tree, parse-tree

Lets say I have the following set of inputs and outputs:

Input:

```
A full sentence: (S (NP (NNP James)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN boy)) (VP (
VBG eating) (NP (NNS sausages))))))
```

Output:

```
James is a boy eating sausages
```

Input: `(NNS Sausages)`

Output: `Sausages`

How could I build a Java program to extract the words from each to create a sentence? (Without using external libraries)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.*?(\\w+)(?:\\)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xMsSFb/2)

`(\\w+)(?:\\)+)` : capture one or more `\\w` followed by one or more `)`

where `\\w` mean `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` , you can also use `([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\)+)` to capture only words

Note : use [`.*?(\\w+)\\)+`](https://regex101.com/r/46ITZ2/1) to make it more efficient as pointed by [shmosel in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884270/given-a-parse-tree-how-can-i-extract-words-to-create-a-sentence/42884311#comment72870993_42884311)

JAVA Demo

```
    String s="(S (NP (NNP James)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN boy)) (VP (VBG eating) (NP (NNS sausages))))))";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?(\\w+)(?:\\)+)", "$1 ").trim());
```

Output :

```
James is a boy eating sausages
```

Demo :

```js
const regex = /.*?(\w+)(?:\)+)/g;
const str = `(S (NP (NNP James)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN boy)) (VP (VBG eating) (NP (NNS sausages))))))
(NNS Sausages)`;
const subst = `$1 `;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The second group doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @shmosel yes , i agree with you , OP can also use `.*?(\\w+)\\)+` , thanks :)

Comment: the demo does not seem like Java to me (`const`??)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher yes it isn't but the displayed code is in java with `replaceAll`, can't run java code here :P

Comment: awsome, I was trying to do it, but wooow you did it faster, i think i need to read more about regex =) Awesome

Answer (score 0):

Given your question is tagged with parse-tree, the customary way would be to:

1. Define a grammar for the language. Construct a parser from the
   grammar.
2. If you're dead-set on not using 3rd part libraries then you
   will have to write a recursive descent parser by hand.
3. Parse the expression into a parse tree.
4. Recursively walk the tree and extract each word token.

Each step is relatively straightforward in its own right.